# Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in

Tags: php

форумчане! У меня вопрос, кто работал с библиотекой PHPExcel? Наткнулся на простенькую, но полезную статью как передать данные из php-кода на страницу экселя: [ссылка на статью](http://tradebenefit.ru/eksport-dannih-iz-php-v-excel). Так вот читая ее можно предложить что все должно работать как часы, если скачать библиотеку и подключить ее как надо. Но в моем случае при выполнении файла с кодом, как в примере, вываливает ошибку:

> Maximum execution time of 30 seconds
> exceeded in
> X:\home\localhost\www\ks\libs\PHPExcel\Shared\XMLWriter.php
> on line 28.

Версия библиотеки 1.8.0. Эта версия что нестабильна, раз такой пример простой не может выполнить? Или автор статьи неверное осветил эту интересную тему? Спасибо за ответы заранее...

Comment: Ну тут дело скорей не в примере, а в настройках сервера. Поскольку пример действительно очень простой. Нужно смотреть настройки сервера.

Comment: Где исполняется код? По идее всё это дело не должно занимать более 2-4 секунд. 

Ошибку вы понимаете?

Comment: Исполняю на денвере код. Превышено ожидание времени...из-за этого ошибка. Неужели для такой пустячной работы не хватает полминуты исполнения кода?

Comment: @IntegralAL проверил у тебя на денвере 1.8.0 версию, всё работает... Файл подключаешь, который Classes/PHPExcel.php?

Comment: Как написал @terantul, я добавил время выполнение в настройках и все заработало. Не знаю почему так, но видимо настройки сервера неправильны были.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам же написано почему не получается:

```
Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
```

Данная ошибка проявляется если скрипт выполняется больше, чем ему разрешено в конфигурации PHP.
В index.php добавьте следующие строчки:

```
<?php ini_set("max_execution_time", "60"); ?>
```

или

```
<?php set_time_limit (60); ?>
```

Или создайте .htaccess следующего содержания:

```
php_value max_execution_time 60
```

Или (как в Вашем случае использвоания локального веб-сервера) измените параметр в php.ini.

Comment: да там потолок исполнения - 2-4 секунды этому скрипту на пк.

Comment: Все заработало спасибо! Про установку времени выполнения я забыл совсем. Но вопрос такой в связи с чем такой простой времени идет на исполнение скрипта? Вообще говорят, что скрипт PHPExcel тяжелый очень, что грузит долго если большие объемы. Это так?

Comment: несомненно правда, дело не только в том, что он создает файл определенной структуры, он еще порядочно кушает память и без всякого рода php акселераторов он вообще может "ложить" компьютер. Некоторые прайсы такие в которых от 5000 до 10000 товаров с категориями и с плюсиками слева занимают до 10гбайт озу и могут генерироваться часами. Для этого используют крон и самое простое время для сервера (например ночь после бекапа). А потом просто выдают уже сгенерированный файл. Но если нужен какой другой мелкий документ то просто проверьте свои настройки сервера должно относительно быстро работать.

Comment: Если вам нужно сгенерировать простой Excel файл то можете воспользовать простым методом. Создаёте html таблицу (без заголовков head и тела body) с указанием в заголовках что это xls таблица. Подробнее можно прочитать тут http://habrahabr.ru/post/133093/

Answer (score 0):

PHPExcel тут совершенно не причем, у вас в файле php.ini есть параметр max_execution_time, который устанавливает максимальное время работы скрипта, в случае если заданное в нем  время будет превышено то php и выбрасывает вот такую ошибку:
Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in X:\home... .

Видимо у вас этом параметре установлено значение 30 секунд, во первых увеличите время в нем.  Во вторых так же в файле  php.ini есть параметр memory_limit  который определяет максимальный объем памяти для выполнения скрипта, можно увеличить и его. В третьих, на моей практике отчет который получается больше 30 секунд, должен быть довольно объемным, если это не так  посмотрите запрос к базе данных,возможно можно как то его облегчить.